# sql oracle question about joins or subquery

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select *
from amazon_shipment, customer
where amazon_shipment.customer_id = customer.customer_id 
and amazon_shipment.customer_id in 
    (select top(1) amazon_shipment.customer_id
    from amazon_shipment 
    group by amazon_shipment.customer_id
    order by count(*) desc);
```

I am trying to select all the customers with the most order, however, I get an error:

> FROM keyword not found were expected

Answer (score 0):

TOP(1) isn't available in Oracle.

In Oracle 11gR2 and lower, you can use WHERE ROWNUM < 2

```
select *
  from EMPLOYEES
 where rownum < 2
 order by SALARY desc;
```

In Oracle 12c and higher, you can use FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY

```
select *
  from EMPLOYEES
 order by SALARY desc
 fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I gave you a upvote for your question. If you need general help on Sqldeveloper, just hit me up.